# Passing a loop index value into NIntegrate

Tags: numerical-integration

I would like to use the NIntegrate[] function to calculate an integral within a Do[] Loop, and pass in the value of the index into the integrand.

As a simple, hypothetical example I would like to calculate the following integrals:

$C_1[T]$= $\int_0^1 \frac{T}1 dx  $

$C_2[T]$= $\int_0^1 \frac{T}2 dx  $

$C_3[T]$= $\int_0^1 \frac{T}3 dx  $

...

$C_j[T]$= $\int_0^1 \frac{T}j dx  $

Let's just say $j$ goes from 1 to 3.

Then I would expect you could easily compute these three integrals in a Do-loop.

For example

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
Do[Subscript[C, j][T_] :=  NIntegrate[(T/j), {x, 0, 1}], {j, 3}]
```

And let's say you want to plot $C_1[T]$...

```
Plot[Subscript[C, 1][T], {T, 0, 1}]
```

When you evaluate the cell, you get the following error:

> NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand 0.0000204286/j has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0,1}}. >>

This indicates that `j` is not being "seen" as it's numerical value, just the variable `j`, and therefore the integrand cannot be numerically integrated.

Does anyone know of a way to pass in the numerical value of the index `j` into `NIntegrate` when you're using it in a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct about having a scoping problem with your indexing variable, but you have another problem as well -- `T` in your `Plot` expression is not a function of `x`. Here is one way you might fix your code.

```
Clear[Subscript]
Do[With[{j = j}, Subscript[C, j][T_] := NIntegrate[(T/j), {x, 0, 1}]], {j, 3}]
Plot[Table[Subscript[C, j][1 + x^2], {j, 3}], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Thanks - that worked;  `x` was intended as a dummy variable for integration.  It seems that the essential, missing component here was using `With{j=j}`

Comment: @E.Scott. Passing an actual argument that is an expressed in terms of `x` to replace your formal argument `T`is just as important using `With`. You have imbedded the symbol `x` into your definition of the various `Subscript[C, j]` forms and it must appear as the independent variable of the integrand.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Table[Integrate[(T/j), {x, 0, 1}], {j, 3}]
```

You are using NIntegrate (numerical integration) but haven't defined T. Either use Integrate (as above) or give T a value.